# Renaming tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I keep getting a **syntax error** in PSQL and I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
SELECT page_code, developer
FROM page
WHERE data_approved=null and approved_by=null
ALTER TABLE page 
RENAME COLUM page_code TO unapproved;
```

Comment: Are you looking for *alias*? I.e do you want `page_code` *be represented* under `unapproved` name?

Comment: Your code Appears as though you want to rename a column for Some rows in a table but not others. That's not how SQL works. You may want to read about UPDATE statements to change the Data in rows.  I recommend you give a very clear example of what you're trying to do and why, after reading this... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are, probably, looking for *alias*, not for *altering table*:

```
 SELECT page_code AS unapproved, 
        developer
   FROM page
  WHERE data_approved IS null 
    AND approved_by IS null
```

Note, that `page` table will stay *intact* while its `page_code` field will be *represented* in this particular query as `unapproved`. Please, be very careful with *altering tables* since doing this you change the rules for *all* the users.

Another issue is `= null` which returns `null` (neither `true` nor `false`). `IS null` is the right syntax.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME new_table_name;

> > this command will help you to change table name
> > Rename is used to change the table name and
> > change is used to rename column name